# Adding a title page, page headers and footers using Pandoc

Tags: pandoc

How do you specify that Pandoc should use a specific header and footer when generating a PDF from Markdown?

Currently I use the following to create my doc from the command line:

```
pandoc -s -V geometry:margin=1in --number-sections -o doc.pdf doc.mkd
```

This gives a lovely result with numbered sections.

What I would like to do, is to include a header and footer on each page. How do I go about it?

The [extensions mechanism](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/pandocs-markdown.html), e.g. `pandoc_title_block` may hold the key, but how do you use it?

Lastly (as a bonus), is there some way to create a title page for a document using pandoc?

Comment: A good answer to this question can be found here, too https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139205/134508

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using the `-s` (`--standalone`) argument for the generation of PDFs, Pandoc uses a specific LateX template.

You can look at the template with `pandoc -D latex` and notice that there are many variables that you can set (the same way you did you with `-V geometry:margin=1in` in your command).

In order to add a specific header/footer, you can modify this template and use the `--template` argument in the command line.

You can get more information here [Pandoc demo templates](https://pandoc.org/demo/example19/Templates.html)

Comment: For others information: The "geometry" variable is not implemented in pandoc included in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
For a possible workaround see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/59mBEixlIJU